Is there a finite dimensional vector space over a finite field with exactly two bases?
Is there a finite dimensional vector space over a finite field with exactly two bases?
I searched and found that the answer is NO. But I have an example that $\mathbb{Z}_{3}$ is a 1-dimensional vector space over itself with two bases namely $\{1\}$ and $\{2\}$.
So, am i doing something wrong?
Please provide the proof or any literature supporting the statement, if any.
Thanks in advance.

depends on the notion of basis. One could argue, that basis is meant modulo a scalar factor, in that case there is only one basis in your example.

May be whatever source said "No!" is not very reliable? You know, some people posting in the internet are wrong :-). FWIW your example is the one that occured to me, and it is easy to see that it is the only one.

But if a basis is a set on independet vectors generating the vector space and two bases are distinct, when they are distinct as sets, which would be the standard definition, then your expample is correct.

This question occurred in a National level exam in India. The correct answer was accepted as NO.

@Rattanverma either some condition is missing (like dimension at least $2$), or your Indian exam solution is wrong.

To give this question an answer:
Any $\mathbb{F}_3$-vector space $V$ of dimension $1$ has exactly two bases, namely the two singletons $\{x\}$ and $\{y\}$, where $x$ and $y$ are the two non-zero elements of $V$.
For counting bases of a vector space there might be the ambiguity whether the order of the basis vectors matters or not. But in this case it doesn't make a difference, as the bases are of size $1$.
